# What is the difference between "Add" and "Linear dodge (Add)" in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

In Photoshop's "Apply Image" dialog window there is one blending mode that is absent in layer's blend mode list. It as Add.

So, **what is the difference between it and "Linear dodge" that already has (Add) in parenthesis and, in fact, is A+B (math Add) blend mode?**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried both and seen the difference? Have you looked for the answer in the photoshop manual?

Comment: My understanding is that they were (at least initially, outside the "Apply Image panel") identical and Linear Dodge was implemented to get around Quantel's patent on the Add blend mode. (I think it's [this one](https://www.google.com/patents/EP0512839A2?cl=en), but I'm not positive.) More info available [here](http://old.siggraph.org/publications/newsletter/v32n3/contributions/phillips.html).

Comment: @user1118321 Ty. So, basically it's all about patents...

Comment: That's my understanding, though I'm no lawyer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you notice `Linear Dodge (Add)` and `Add` appear, by default, the same. However, that is only by default.

Both `Add` and `Subtract` within the *Apply Image panel* gives you the `Offset` and `Scale` functions.

Scale isn't going to be too helpful here but Offset can Lighten or Darken the results based on a value between -255 and +255.